# Nuxt 2.x build inlcudes inline script which violates the Content Security Policy directive of Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, nuxt.js

Recently i updated my Nuxt project to version 2.x
After build I'v got error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tempUn1btibnrWwQxEk37lMGV1Nf8FO/GXxNhLEsPdg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

The reason of this error is inline script provided by Nuxt build
In version 1.x of Nuxt there was no inline scripts provided to index file

This is generated index.html body

```
  <div id="__nuxt"><style>#nuxt-loading{visibility:hidden;opacity:0;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;animation:nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;-webkit-animation:nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;animation-fill-mode:forwards;overflow:hidden}@keyframes nuxtLoadingIn{0%{visibility:hidden;opacity:0}20%{visibility:visible;opacity:0}100%{visibility:visible;opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn{0%{visibility:hidden;opacity:0}20%{visibility:visible;opacity:0}100%{visibility:visible;opacity:1}}#nuxt-loading>div,#nuxt-loading>div:after{border-radius:50%;width:5rem;height:5rem}#nuxt-loading>div{font-size:10px;position:relative;text-indent:-9999em;border:.5rem solid #f5f5f5;border-left:.5rem solid #c93b28;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-ms-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-animation:nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;animation:nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear}#nuxt-loading.error>div{border-left:.5rem solid #ff4500;animation-duration:5s}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes nuxtLoading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}</style><script>window.addEventListener("error",function(){var e=document.getElementById("nuxt-loading");e&&(e.className+=" error")})</script><div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status"><div>Loading...</div></div></div>
```

I expect to handle this some how, By disabling chrome policy or by bundling nuxt without inline scripts

EDIT
after deleted inline script, error dissappear, but nothing more render... There should be Vue app

Comment: It seems like you have a CSP policy enabled which prevents you from executing inline scripts. Modify this policy by adding `unsafe-inline` to it (don't do this), add a hash or a nonce or just remove your inline code if it is not necessary. The policy is usually sent along with an HTTP response in the header (`Content-Security-Policy`).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 how add hash or nonce ? After remove inline script, error dissapear but nothing happen more...

Comment: With a hash, you need to add the hash of the `<script>` (the value which is shown to you in the devtools) to the CSP policy (see [the format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)). Then, it will work. With a nonce, you need to add the nonce to your CSP policy (a generated unique value for each request) and also to the `<script>` tag as an attribute. The CSP policy is usually sent along as a header. If the script rarely changes, you could use a static hash.